# Add Role on Server

Tags: python, discord.py

I intend, if you send the bot a certain DM that it then gives a role on a certain server.

This is my code what I tried:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot:
        return
  elif message.content.startswith("++neunundvierzig++"):
        role = message.author.guild.get_role(861543456908640298)
        guild = bot.get_guild(816021180435529758)
        await message.channel.send("Erfolgreich Zerifiziert!")
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

It says in the log:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aaa12\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\HTML CSS JS Py Projekte\Python\bot_check\bot.py", line 36, in on_message
    role = message.author.guild.get_role(861543456908640298)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Comment: And... what happened when you tried this? Surely, you don't expect us to go *create a Discord bot* to see what your code does. Did you get a syntax error? A runtime error? No feedback? What happened?

Comment: I have edit my message with the error

Comment: Is the user in the guild?

Comment: yes, it is in the guild

Comment: You never use `guild` in your code and have not defined `member`. Maybe give this a try? After defining `member` and leaving out `guild` it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Do you mean it so?

`async def on_message(message, member: discord.Member):`

and 

`role = message.author.get_role(861543456908640298)`

Comment: No, `member = message.author`

Comment: it doesn't go. the same error still occurs

Comment: Have you enabled Intents? Also: Please tag the person you are giving an answer with an `@PersonYouWantToMention`

Answer (score 0):

I think you defined `role` wrong. Your code says that `message.author.guild` doesn't exist, so you should try `message.guild`.

Like this:

```
role = message.guild.get_role(861543456908640298)
```

Aside from that, you don't defined `member`. Just rename it to `await message.author.add_roles(role)` instead of `await member.add_roles(role)`

---

### Sources

- [Discord Messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.Message)

Comment: It works, but my goal is if you write a private message to the bot that he then gives the message author a role on my server